# PHP: Lower hierarchy class access public function from upper hierarchy class

Tags: php, oop, scope, hierarchy

Consider the following code:

```
class Upper {
    private $lower;
    function __construct($passme1, $passme2) {
        if(!class_exists("Lower")) {
            include 'path/to/file.php';
        }
        $this->lower = new Lower($passme1, $passme2);
    }
    //functions
    public function foo() {
        //queries database and returns user specific information
    }
}
```

And in the linked file I have the class Lower:

```
class Lower {
    function __construct($passme1, $passme2) {
        //sort the passed variables out
    }
    public function bar() {
        //trying to access the public function foo of class Upper
    }
}
```

I have found myself needing to access the function foo of class Upper from within the function bar of class Lower.

Is this at all possible?

Thank you,
Joe

Comment: Very little info on what the purpose is, it depends on the design how to approach this _problem_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `Upper::foo()` from `Lower::bar()` you have to pass the `$this` variable as argument:

In class Lower:

```
public function bar (Upper $upper) {
    $upper->foo();
}
```

And in some method of class Upper:

```
$this->lower->bar($this);
```

---

P.s.: If you don't need access to `$this` in `Upper::foo()` you may want to declare the method as `static` and then do in `Lower::bar()`:

```
Upper::foo(); // calls static method foo of class Upper
```